# Adding Views with Java LayoutInflater in a loop either doesn't set the width or only adds the first item in the loop

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I have function that loads data form a server, like a search then adds these tot the main menu.
To accomplish this I am using a for loop on the JSON results to add the items.

This loop works fine, it reads the data and loops through fine:

Java Loop:

```
JSONArray teams = result.getJSONArray("teams");
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) mainMenu.findViewById(R.id.team_list_view);
//Log.d("TEAMS",teams.toString());
for(int x = 0; x < teams.length(); x++) {
     JSONObject cTeam = teams.getJSONObject(x);
     String name = cTeam.getString("name");
     String thumb = cTeam.getString("thumb");
     String id = cTeam.getString("id");
     View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teams_menu_template, null);
     int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
     int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

     ImageButton pp = (ImageButton) custom.findViewById(R.id.tempPPbtn);
     Button teamName = (Button) custom.findViewById(R.id.tempPPTxtbtn);
     teamName.setText(name);

     loadImage loadImage = new loadImage("imagebutton",pp);
     loadImage.execute(thumb);

     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);

     parent.addView(custom);

 }
```

Now this does work fine it loops through and adds the image and text and appends to the parent layout. But instead of stacking the new layouts it places them side by side like in the image below:

[image: side by instead of stacked]

After some googling I tried adding params to set the width to FILL_PARENT but the outcome only adds the first item. However it does add it as I want.[image: with big gap]

I've stuck on this for quite some time, if anyone can help it would be greatly appriated.

My Template XML file i'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tempDropCont"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_down"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:baselineAligned="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/tempPPbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/profile"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/leader_board"
                android:id="@+id/tempPPTxtbtn"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tempDrop"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/view_team"
                    android:id="@+id/tempTxtBtn1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/edit_team"
                    android:id="@+id/tempTxtBtn2"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/team_settings"
                    android:id="@+id/tempTxtBtn3"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At first I did think it was the xml but I have tried using include on a different layout and it includes the file fine as its supposed too.

NOTE from the server there is two items returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice to have the parent layout as well, or at least the way you defined the parent (LinearLayout with the id listview).
However, there are several culprits for the behavior that you describe:

1. Make sure that the parent layout has the orientation set to vertical. At this point you can copy paste a couple of template items in your layout and see if they look alright when you define them in xml
2. When you inflate your item, you need to pass the parent as well, so that the child inherits the layout properties:

   `View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teams_menu_template, parent, false);`

This will create the item with the expected properties as defined in the parent container, but not attach it to the parent just yet.

3. This line is not used:

   `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);`

You don't set the parameters once you created them. But I think this will be redundant once you do the inflation properly.

Comment: It was the parent layout I had it set to horizontal, changed it to vertical and worked straight away